# Is it possible to disable EclipseLink weaving changetracking only for several entities?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Using EclipseLink 2.6.0 on WebLogic 12.2.1.4.0 I started to get the following exception upon invoking `EntityManager.merge()`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.AttributeChangeTrackingPolicy.updateListenerForSelfMerge(AttributeChangeTrackingPolicy.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.mergeIntoObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3524)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeCloneWithReferences(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3484)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.mergeInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:530)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:97)
    at weblogic.persistence.TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.invoke(TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.java:164)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5085.merge(Unknown Source)
    at com.acme.dao.Dao.save(Dao.java:86)
```

I found a workaround which is setting

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving.changetracking" value="false"/>
```

in `persistence.xml`
However, this disables weaving changetracking for the whole persistence unit which might have an undesired global impact.

The transaction involves a bunch of objects with twisted `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` relationships and the exception is thrown only when trying to delete one of the objects and merging another.

My question is: **is it possible to disable weaving changetracking only for the entities involved in the transaction where the NullPointerException occurs?**

I have tried adding `@Mutable` annotations on the fields and all types of `@ChangeTracking` on the entities but none of those eliminated the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Are you changing ID properties in entities? Most other NPE in change tracking seem to have resulted from that, and just turning off weaving causes other issues with the approach that are less noticeable. If you can debug or reproduce what is null, I'd suggest filling a bug. Otherwise, the @ChangeTracking is the right way to go - does it affect the NPE at all? In this case, it is caused by a merge as it cascades through a reference mapping, then into 2 collection mappings, so deferred change tracking would need to be on entities 3 nodes deep. You might also turn off cascade merge option.

Comment: Thanks @Chris The Ids of the entities aren't changed. The NPE occurs on delete. However, one of the entities involved does not have a primary key on a single column but its primary key is two columns with the same Ids as other entities. So it's kind of: PRODUCT(id_product) SHOP(id_shop) PRODUCT_AT_SHOP(id_product, id_shop) There is a @ ManyToOne lazy cascade.all annotation from PRODUCT to PRODUCT_AT_SHOP and a @ ManyToOne + @ JoinColumn from PRODUCT_AT_SHOP to both PRODUCT and SHOP. When trying to remove the SHOP the NPE is thrown.

Comment: I tried every @ ChangeTracking mode on the entities without luck. But I only tried the top level entities. There are other nested entities. I shall give a try to a more aggressive deferred @ ChangeTracking on every field of the entities involved.

Comment: How are you removing Shop then? I'm guessing you are modifying Product so it no longer references the ProductAtShop associated to the shop to be removed. Check that you aren't modifying the ProductAtShop - it should not have its product reference nulled out and just needs to be deleted.

Comment: @ChangeTracking should be used on the entities, not the fields/properties. Be sure to use it on the Product and Shop entities, as they have collection mappings to ProductAtShop that seems likely involved.